# Android studio 4.1 is not showing errors into IDE

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-4.1

Recently I have updated android studio with Android Studio 4.1, but after updating, the studio isn't showing errors in IDE with red underline or red bar right side. Every time I run the app it throws a single error after compilation. So it's very difficult to say where is the error

Does anyone have an idea of what to do?

NOTE: invalidate cache & restart, sync project, clean, rebuild not working

Comment: File - Invalidate and Restart.

Comment: @PrajwalWaingankar not working

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For Ubuntu users
If your android studio not opening properly after updated.
Just press CTR+H in FileManager (show hidden files). now you can see the .local file.
now go to remove the google file from there. (Path -> local/share/google).

Comment: Try to restart 2 - 3 times and check or else follow the above steps.

Comment: How to fix it in windows?

Comment: How to fix it in windows plz

Answer (score 7):

In Windows go to `C:\Users\{USER_NAME}\AppData\Roaming\Google\` and delete the `AndroidStudio4.1` folder and start your Android studio then it will ask to import settings, do not import any settings, instead continue with setup and the problem will be solved.

Comment: Thanks I wasted 2 days searching for it finally someone got the answer

Answer (score 2):

I encouontered the same problem and after a lot of restarts, invalidating caches, cleaning, rebuilding, deleting `.idea` and `.gradle` files I realized all I needed to to was to update my Kotlin Version on the classpath - i.e. build - project file.

My Kotlin Version was 1.4.32 but I upgareded it to 1.5.0

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.1'
        classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$navigationVersion"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.0"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
```